# Getting error (FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown") while running docker-compose

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to create a docker environment with `php-fpm` and `nginx` using docker-compose. I am trying to avoid using the images available for learning purpose.

i have been to stich most of it together but failing at the time when it matters the most, accessing the site.

here is what i have done so far:

created a `Dockerfile` for nginx

```
FROM nginx:latest

EXPOSE 80
COPY /etc/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY . /var/www/wordpress
```

the nginx.conf is as follows:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  _;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
    root   /var/www/wordpress;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /var/www/wordpress;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    root           /var/www/wordpress;
    fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
       deny  all;
    } 
}
```

PHP-dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM  php:8.1.1-fpm-buster
RUN echo "$PHP_INI_DIR"
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
COPY /etc/fpm-www.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
EXPOSE 9000
```

www.conf is as follows

```
[global]
daemonize = no

[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
access.log = /dev/stdout
slowlog = /dev/stdout
listen = 9000
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 100
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
pm.status_path = /status
ping.path = /fpm-ping
```

all this seems to be working file for now, that means:

1- the images are built and the containers are started
2- accessing localhost- I get welcome to nginx

but when i try to access index.php (copied to /var/www/wordpress and is available in the container) I get the following error:

`nginx_1  | 172.23.0.1 - - [24/Dec/2021:12:17:49 +0000] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 27 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36 Edg/96.0.1054.62" "-"`

I have tried multiple options and posts available but my knowledge of nginx-php-docker-compose seems to be missing something.

I am certain it is something fundamental which I have overlooked.

Kindly suggest

Comment: Your php files are not present on your php-fpm container. From your nginx conf, they should be available there inside the `/scripts` directory. Either copy them as well to that target dir or find an other way to make them available (i.e. docker volume shared between containers).

Comment: yes, this was indeed the reason, I added a  volume and it worked !